# TeeChart examples

Tags: teechart

I have TeeChart 8 Standard as part off Delphi XE2, recently asked for advice regarding features of TeeChart and was told I could look in the All Features\etc... to find example code. I downloaded the zipped TeeChart2010_Examples file from Steema, and ran the Tee9New.exe which shows the All features... cascade of sub-directories. In this I can find examples of what I want, but the SourceCode tab suggests I need to install TChart Pro to see the source code.

Is the source code of the examples only available after installation of the Pro version? I believe I could install the Evaluation version to confirm this, but don't want to 'mess' with my already functioning Standard version that came with Delphi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeeChart Std evaluation version also comes with the source code for the demo. It's available at, for example, *C:\Program Files\Steema Software\TeeChart Standard 2012 for RAD XE2\Examples\Features*. However, if you need the source code to a specific demo please let me know which is it and I'll send it to you.

Comment: Thanks @Narcis,  I understand that. But what I want to confirm is that installing the evaluation version won't override the standard version already installed with XE2. I want to make sure that the **existing** standard version will continue operating, as I don't want the nag screens to start appearing where I use TeeCharts in my current projects.

Comment: When installing TeeChart Pro or Standard, the version included with the IDE is backed up. It can be restored manually when needed. You can also look at the feature matrix here http://www.steema.com/featurematrix/vcl to see if the concrete features you need are included with the Standard version or only with the Pro.